# Line up Solid Gauge horizontally by editing SVG File

Tags: python, svg, gauge, pygal

I have one SVG image created through Pygal, that I am using in one dashboard. However the gauges in the SVG image are vertically stacked, I want to line up horizontally.

Current Result.
[image]

Below is the image of the expected result. If I can render it through Pygal directly, that would be great, if not any other solution is highly appreciated.

[image: Result Expected]

```
DataStorageGauge = pygal.SolidGauge(half_pie=True,inner_radius=0.70,style=pygal.style.styles['default'](value_font_size=20))
DataStorageGauge.add(Series 1, [{'value': 225000, 'max_value': 1275000}],formatter = storage_formatter)
DataStorageGauge.add(Series 2, [{'value': 110, 'max_value': 100}],formatter = percent_formatter)
DataStorageGauge.render_data_uri()
```

Comment: Can you add some of your code to your question so that we can see how you https://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/output.html these two gauges.

Comment: I've edited and added the code I've used for Solid Gauge.